# Django circular import AppRegistryNotReady error

Tags: python, django, django-models

i' ve Django 1.9.2 with python 3.4.2 in a virtualenvironment.

I' ve many applications, and the 2 related are common and shop.

common/models.py contains:

```
from django.apps import apps

class Document(CLDate):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    assessmentorder = models.ForeignKey(apps.get_model('shop', 'AssessmentOrder'), blank=True, null=True)
```

shop/models.py contains:

```
from common.models import ServiceModel

class AssessmentOrder(CLDate):
    """AssessmentOrder model"""
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order)
    comment = models.TextField()
```

.

This is a circular import, and i read many strategy to resolve it (including apps.get_model), but none of them seem to work for me. I also tried

```
apps.get_model('shop.AssessmentOrder')
```

, but the same. The complete error message is the following:

```
File "/home/hidden/.virtualenvs/sccdb34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/hidden/.virtualenvs/sccdb34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
autoreload.raise_last_exception()
File "/home/hidden/.virtualenvs/sccdb34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 249, in raise_last_exception
six.reraise(*_exception)
File "/home/hidden/.virtualenvs/sccdb34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
raise value.with_traceback(tb)
File "/home/hidden/.virtualenvs/sccdb34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/hidden/.virtualenvs/sccdb34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
File "/home/hidden/.virtualenvs/sccdb34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
app_config.import_models(all_models)
File "/home/hidden/.virtualenvs/sccdb34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 202, in import_models
self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
File "/home/hidden/.virtualenvs/sccdb34/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "/home/hidden/git/sccdb/sccdb/common/models.py", line 25, in <module>
class Document(CLDate):
File "/home/hidden/git/sccdb/sccdb/common/models.py", line 28, in Document
assessmentorder = models.ForeignKey(apps.get_model('shop.AssessmentOrder'), blank=True, null=True)
File "/home/hidden/.virtualenvs/sccdb34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 194, in get_model
self.check_models_ready()
File "/home/hidden/.virtualenvs/sccdb34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 131, in check_models_ready
raise AppRegistryNotReady("Models aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.
```

Is it somehow related to my django version or python3, or what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of doing using `get_model` function in foreign key declaration, you can simply put the model name as string and it'll still work:

```
assessmentorder = models.ForeignKey('shop.AssessmentOrder', blank=True, null=True)
```

This should resolve the issue

Comment: Hm, i tried this previously, and it resulted only error, but in the forms. I was careless, and did not read it carefully. Now it works! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Don't include models, just put a path to them. As it described in [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey)

```
from django.conf import settings

class Document(CLDate):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    assessmentorder = models.ForeignKey('shop.AssessmentOrder', blank=True, null=True)
```

And

```
class AssessmentOrder(CLDate):
    """AssessmentOrder model"""
    order = models.ForeignKey('yourapp.Order')
    comment = models.TextField()
```

Comment: Well, i tried to change the related stuffs, but it' s still the same error.

Comment: You tried to remove it with `apps.get_model('shop', 'AssessmentOrder')`? Or tried solution provided in that answer?

Comment: I tried both, but it worked onlz with 'shop.AssessmentOrder', with apps.get_model(...) didn' t.